# Creating an index with REST API

Tags: apache, api, http, rest, curl

I'm trying to create an index within a set under a specific namespace, but am unsure how to do it.

My resources have this as an HTTP example:

```
POST /example/v1/index/{namespace}/{set}/{indexName}
```

and for an example input:

```
 {
 "fields": [
     { "indexField": "firstName", "indexReverseOrder": true },
     { "indexField": "lastName" }
 ],
 "options": {
     "isUnique": true
 }
}
```

this consumes

```
application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

but when I write this out as

```
curl -X POST exampleurl.com/example/v1/index/example_namespace/example_set/example
set -d " {
 "fields": [
     { "indexField": "firstName", "indexReverseOrder": true },
     { "indexField": "lastName" }
 ],
 "options": {
     "isUnique": true
 } }" -H "Content-type : application/json;charset=UTF-8"
```

I get the following HTTP status code

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
```

Can anyone explain to me what's going on  and how I might fix this? Also, let me know if you don't have enough information about the API to understand it, thanks!

**EDIT:**

As some sort of a reference, for this API when I create a set in a namespace I do:

```
curl -X POST http://exampleurl.com/example/v1/store/example_namespace -d "example_set" -H "Content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"
```

and this is successful. I thought indexes would be similar to this, but apparently not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the bash shell misinterpreting the double quotes before the json

```
curl -X POST exampleurl.com/example/v1/index/example_namespace/example_set/example
set -d " {
 "fields": [
     { "indexField": "firstName", "indexReverseOrder": true },
     { "indexField": "lastName" }
 ],
 "options": {
 "isUnique": true
 } }" -H "Content-type : application/json;charset=UTF-8"
```

should be:

```
curl -X POST exampleurl.com/example/v1/index/example_namespace/example_set/example
set -d ' {
 "fields": [
     { "indexField": "firstName", "indexReverseOrder": true },
     { "indexField": "lastName" }
 ],
 "options": {
 "isUnique": true
 } }' -H "Content-type : application/json;charset=UTF-8"
```

The difference is the single quotes encapsulating the json. The bash shell will give an error in trying to execute the command.

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo in your media type:

```
application/json;charset=UTF=8
```

Should be:

```
application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: ah, yes. Just a typographical error when posting the question. It's sound when I made the call